# Take a galois group $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ isomorphic to $C_{16}$. How many subfields $L$ exist such that $[K:L] = 4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Take a galois group $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ isomorphic to $C_{16}$. How many subfields $L$ exist such that $[K:L] = 4$?

I am inclined to say 4 but I cannot prove it.

Comment: Why do you think it's $4$?

Answer (score 2):

By the Galois correspondence, only one.  For $C_{16}$ has a unique subgroup of order $4$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

This is exactly Galois theorem : you have a one to one correspondance between the sub-fields of degree 4 of $L$ and the subgroups of $C_{16}$ with 4 elements.